# Make the suggestions of an autocomplete exposed form clickable

Tags: 7, views

I'm using Drupal 7 and Views.

I have an exposed form of type "autocomplete".

I would like the suggestions to be clickable, which avoids having to click on apply.

Do you know how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Install [Better Exposed Filters module](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters#:%7E:text=The%20Better%20Exposed%20Filters%20module,for%20a%20better%20user%20experience.) , got to your views, in *Advanced* section In **Exposed form style:** select *better exposed* .

> The Better Exposed Filters module replaces the Views' default single-
> or multi-select boxes with radio buttons or checkboxes, respectively.
> Description fields and Select All/None links can be added to exposed
> filters to make for a better user experience. Views Filters is a
> powerful tool to refine the results returned by a given view. When you
> expose a filter, you allow the user to interact with the view making
> it easy to build a customized, advanced search. For example, exposing
> the node type field as a filter lets your site visitor limit their
> search queries to just blog entries. Better Exposed Filters gives you
> greater control over the rendering of exposed filters.
>
> Why use this module? Because it provides a better user experience than
> the default option. Try telling a client that they should click on an
> option, then scroll to the next option and ctrl+click on it. Don't
> just click 'cause you'll lose your first selection. Oh, and ctrl+click
> again to unselect an option... Yeah, not user friendly.

additionally,

> **What else can you do with BEF?**.
> The BEF handbook page provides some basic recipes making exposed
> filters a much better user experience.
>
> Add help text for each exposed filter Tame long lists with scrollable
> checkbox/radio button lists or select all/none links Provide instant
> feedback by updating the View using AJAX whenever an exposed filter is
> changed Use the jQuery Slider widget for greater-than, less-than or
> in-between types of filters If you've got any ideas not covered on the
> handbook page, add a feature request to the issue queue. You can also
> rate this module on DrupalModules.

Comment: Thanks, i know this module, but the problem is that I want to have a form, not checkboxes

Comment: @Hgfdsoiu
what do you mean about the form? this module can support the autocomplete text field as well.

Comment: @Hgfdsoiu check  better expose fields settings

Comment: @Hgfdsoiu what kind of field you have autocomplete?

Comment: This is the tags field. I am trying the module again ...

Comment: By form I mean a text field indeed, like a search form